# Sqoop Import Error: UnsupportedClassVersionError CDH 5.16

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, sqoop, cloudera, cloudera-cdh

I am running `CDH 5.16` on a `rhel7` system. I installed `CDH using packages`.

When I am trying to run `Sqoop` import job from MySQL Server located in a remote server, I am getting following error:

```
Warning: /usr/lib/sqoop/../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
19/06/03 18:39:43 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6-cdh5.16.1
19/06/03 18:39:43 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
19/06/03 18:39:43 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Preparing to use a MySQL streaming resultset.
19/06/03 18:39:43 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/mysql/jdbc/Driver : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.makeConnection(SqlManager.java:872)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager.getConnection(GenericJdbcManager.java:52)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:762)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:785)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnInfoForRawQuery(SqlManager.java:288)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypesForRawQuery(SqlManager.java:259)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypes(SqlManager.java:245)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.ConnManager.getColumnTypes(ConnManager.java:333)
        at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.getColumnTypes(ClassWriter.java:1858)
        at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generate(ClassWriter.java:1657)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:106)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:494)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:621)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:147)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:183)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:234)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:243)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:252)
```

This is my sqoop import statement:

`sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://10.188.177.228:3306/sales --username vaishak --password root_123 --table categories --m 1 --target-dir /user/hive/warehouse/sales.db/categories`

my java version is :

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_212"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-b04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.212-b04, mixed mode)
```

This is the java that is installed during Cloudera manager installation.

I went through the following stackoverflow link and wasn't much helpfull in this case:
[Sqoop import failed, UnsupportedClassVersionError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16692205/sqoop-import-failed-unsupportedclassversionerror)

Before CDH, I had setup Hadoop version 3 along with sqoop separately(outside CDH) and was able to run sqoop scripts successfully.

But i am unable to figure out the issue here. I am also unable to find out the `HADOOP_PREFIX`, `JAVA_HOME` path.

I have downloaded and placed mysql connector `mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar` in `/usr/lib/sqoop/lib` path before starting import statement.

I am new to Setting up Hadoop Components especially using CDH.

Comment: The error is saying Java 8 is not supported. Nothing to do strictly with Hadoop or Sqoop. You might want to verify which versions of Java that CDH 5.16 works with

Comment: As per cloudera documentation, 5.16 and higher releases support Java 8.cloudera link:https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/6/release-notes/topics/rg_java_requirements.html . This is the reason why i am also confused. Java version is supported by CDH. Not sure why this error is cropping up now.

Comment: @cricket_007 Do you think this error has something to do with the sql connector used?

Comment: It's possible. I'd be surprised if the driver you have was only for Java 7, though

Comment: its not the problem with the driver. The driver does support java 1.8. Unable to figure out whats causing this now...

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but I would think CDH included the mysql connector on its own. Especially if you have a Hive metastore or Oozie database already configured for mysql

Comment: i added a `$JAVA_HOME` variable and thinks started working now. though i am facing a new issue now which is a topic for new thread!

Comment: Strange. That would imply you have more than one Java version installed on the machine. I think there's a `sqoop-env` file somewhere that controls that variable, too

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue!. It seems like there were two versions of java that were installed. I removed the older version of java and things started working now!